# RoR 4 Receiving CSV file via API

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload

I am very new to API and am trying to figure out how I can accept a CSV file from a user via API.  Typically the user would upload the file via an online form, but this particular user needs to upload it via an API.  The CSV file uploaded is typically be less then 10-15 megs.  I want to create an API that accepts a post message, with credentials sent via Basic Auth and the csv file in the message.  I have the auth part working, but am unsure how to proceed with getting the file.  I have read posts that use paperclip and other gems, but I want to do this without using any additional gems.  Is it as simple as coding:

uploaded_io = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I accomplished this.  Again, being my first time working with an API, I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but would love to hear from someone who has more experience how this can be improved.

```
before_action :authenticate

def create

  upload_io = params[:file_name]
  file_name = DateTime.now.strftime("%m%d%Y%H%M%S") + File.extname(upload_io.original_filename)

  [... Code to save to AWS removed ...]

  if @upload.save
    render json: "File Successfully Uploaded", status: 200
  else
    render json: "File Upload Failed", status: 422
  end

end
```

And I used the following CURL statement to test it:

```
curl -F "file_name=@test.csv" -u "test@gmail.com:test" http://localhost:8080/api/upload
```

Is there any benefit of receiving the information as multipart/form?